# I cannot print the element when the function return address for reverse string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm recently writing a function to reverse a string input.
For example, input = "hello", then output = "olleh"
I got a question, when I return the address of char*, it looks fine, but why I cannot print the string of that pointer ?

many thanks at first and here is my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* reverseString(char*);

int main(void)
{
    char* s = "hello";
    char* out;

    out = reverseString(s);

    printf("%p %s\n", out, out);
    return 0;
}

char* reverseString(char* s)
{
    int i;
    int size;
    char* reverse;

    size = sizeof(s);
    char reversechar[size];

    for (i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
        reversechar[i - 1] = s[size - i];

    reverse = reversechar;
    //printf("%p\n",reverse);
    return reverse;
}
```

result : 
0x7fff40db7300 @@

Comment: `reverse` points to memory on the stack, being valid only inside `reverseString`. The moment `reverseString` returned this memory had already been dealloctated.

Comment: Also this `size = sizeof(s);` does not do what you'd expect. It returns the size of `s`. `s` is a pointer, and a pointers size is either 4 or 8 depending on the platform. Use  `strlen()` instead.

Comment: Consider pushing up the compiler's warning level to the maximum, then fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Then compile with symbols and run the code inside a debugger tracing through  it step by step, inspecting all relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then you still face issues come back here.

Comment: This isn't valid C++; please don't tag C questions as C++.

Answer (score 2):

Don't allocate `reversechar` inside the function. It will go out of scope when the function returns (i.e. it is not valid to access it anymore). Instead allocate it in main and pass a pointer to the function. Something like:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void reverseString(char* dst, char* s)
 {
    int i;
    int size;

    size = strlen(s);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
      dst[i] = s[size-1-i];

    // Terminate the string
    dst[size] = 0;

 }

 int main(void)
 {
    char* s = "hello";
    char out[strlen(s)+1];

    reverseString(out, s);

    printf("%p %s\n",out,out);

    return 0;
 }
```

Compare this to functions like `strcpy` and `memcpy`. They don't allocate memory for you. They require you to give both the source and the destination pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Several things in your code:

-you try to return a pointer to an array that has automatic storage duration which invokes Undefined Behavior if you use it.

-when trying to print a pointer,cast `(void *)` to it.

-Use `strlen()` function to obtain the length of the string,not `sizeof` operator`.

You should allocate an array dynamically using `malloc()` inside your function,and free it later when finished.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverseString(char*);

int main(void)
{
    char* s = "hello";
    char* out;

    out = reverseString(s);

    printf("%p %s\n", (void *)out, out);

    free(out);
    return 0;
}

char* reverseString(char* s)
{
    char *reverse;
    size_t i, size;

    size = strlen(s);
    char *reversechar = malloc(size + 1);

    for (i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
        reversechar[i - 1] = s[size - i];

    reverse = reversechar;
    //printf("%p\n",reverse);
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: No need to cast the result of `malloc()`. In C void-pointers convert perfectly fine to any other pointer-type.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h> // for strlen

char* reverseString(char* s)
{
    int i;
    int size;
    char* reverse;

    // size = sizeof(s);
    // char reversechar[size];
    // 　↓
    size = strlen(s);
    char* reversechar = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char)); // memory allocation and zero-initialization

    for (i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
        reversechar[i - 1] = s[size - i];

    reverse = reversechar;
    //printf("%p\n",reverse);
    return reverse; // it is necessary that return value is freed by the caller
}
```

```
1. size of string

char* s = "hello world";

Address(64bit)　　  h  e  l  l  o     w  o  r  l  d  /0
0x00007FFF40DB7300：68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 00

  s・・・0x00007FFF40DB7300
  sizeof(s)・・・8  (64bit)
  strlen(s)・・・11 (string length)

In the case of 「char s[] = "hello world";」

  sizeof(s)・・・12 (allocation size)


2. initialization

char buf[5];
0x0000xxxxx22DD100：CD CD CD CD CD (5bytes)

char* buf = malloc(5);
0x0000xxxxx8212A00：CD CD CD CD CD (5bytes)

char* buf = calloc(5 * sizeof(char));
0x0000xxxxx55A6600：00 00 00 00 00 (5bytes)(zero-values)
```

Comment: please excuse me if there are mistakes in my desk-checking code.

Comment: No need to cast the result of `malloc()`. In C void-pointers convert perfectly fine to any other pointer-type.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: A simple `malloc()` would do very well here.

Comment: If that is malloc(), "memset(reversechar, 0x00, sizeof(char) * (size + 1)" is necessary.
"sizeof(char)" is for avoiding constant value.

Comment: #include<algorithm>　std::reverse(s, s + strlen(s));