# Print pointer string which is return from function in C

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, strlen, function-definition

Trying to write a C program to reverse the given string (using Pointer) and here is the code.

[sample.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _len(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i++] != '\0');
    return i;
}

char *_reverse(char s[])
{
    int len = _len(s);
    char *r = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    for (int i=len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        *r++ = s[i];
    }

    *r = '\0';  // Line 21
    r -= len;   // Line 22
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char s[10] = "Hello";
    printf("Actual String: %s\n", s);
    printf("Reversed: %s\n", _reverse(s));
    return 0;
}
```

**Current O/P:**

```
Actual String: Hello

Reversed: (null)
```

**Expected O/P:**

```
Actual String: Hello

Reversed: olleH
```

What is wrong or missing in here..? Please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't add a '\0' to the end of the char array

Comment: @pavi2410 Same result after adding `*r = '\0'` before of return statement in the function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36965437/7595401

Comment: Do not use underscores in naming of functions or variables. It is a) not allowed by C standard b) Does not add anything to the code (and only reducing the readability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that the `_len` function is by definition incorrect, it is supposed to exclude the last `'\0'` terminator (should be: `return i-1;`). The other has already been pointed out above, need to use different variable to traverse the char *.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _len(char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i++] != '\0');
    return i-1;
}

char *_reverse(char s[]) {
    int len = _len(s);
    //printf("Len: %d\n", len);
    char *r =  (char *) malloc((len+1) * sizeof(char));
    char *ptr = r;
    for (int i=len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //printf("%d %c\n", i, s[i]);
        *(ptr++) = s[i];
    }
    *(ptr++) = '\0';
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char s[10] = "Hello";
    printf("Actual String: %s\n", s);
    printf("Reversed: %s\n", _reverse(s));
    return 0;
}
```

```
Actual String: Hello
Reversed: olleH
```

Comment: Thank you, Fixed now. (`_len()` function is a big mistake) & just for an extra note that instead of declaring another one pointer (i.e, *ptr), as @Julien said adding  `r -= len;` also working perfectly.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the pointer "r" of your newly allocated memory. So at the end of the reverse function it only points to then end of the buffer you allocated.
You can move it back to the beginning by doing:

```
r -= len;
```

But to simplify things I'd recommend leaving r at the start using i and len to compute the index.

Also, you don't terminate the reversed string with a '\0'.

Comment: Added (Pl check 'Line 22').. Still same results.

Answer (score 2):

You increase `r` in the loop, then return it. Obviously, it points to an address after the actual reversed string. Copy r to another variable after `malloc` and return that.

Answer (score 0):

The first function implementation

```
int _len(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i++] != '\0');
    return i;              // Old code
}
```

though has no standard behavior and declaration nevertheless is more or less correct. Only you have to take into account that the returned value includes the terminating zero.

As a result this memory allocation

```
char *r = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
```

is correct.

However the initial value of the variable `i` in the for loop

```
for (int i=len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

is incorrect because the index expression `len - 1` points to the terminating zero of the source string that will be written in the first position of the new string. As a result the new array will contain an empty string.

On the other hand, this function definition (that you showed in your post after updating it)

```
int _len(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i++] != '\0');
    // return i;              // Old code
    return i == 0 ? i : i-1;  // Line 9 (Corrected)
}
```

does not make a great sense because `i` never can be equal to 0 due to the prost-increment operator in the while loop. And moreover now the memory allocation

```
char *r = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
```

is incorrect. There is no space for the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Also it is a bad idea to prefix identifiers with an underscore. Such names can be reserved  by the system.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t len( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

To reverse a string there is no need to allocate memory/ If you want to create a new string and copy the source string in the reverse order then the function must be declared like

```
char * reverse( const char * s );
```

that is the parameter shall have the qualifier `const`. Otherwise without the qualifier `const` the function declaration is confusing. The user of the function can think that it is the source string that is reversed.

So if the function is declared like

```
char * reverse( char *s );
```

then it can be defined the following way.

```
char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = len( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

If you want to create a new string from the source string in the reverse order then the function can look like

```
char * reverse_copy( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = len( s );

    char *result = malloc( len + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        while ( n != 0 )
        {
            result[i++] = s[--n];
        }

        result[i] = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}
```

And you should not forget to free the result array in main when it is not needed any more.

For example

```
char s[10] = "Hello";
printf("Actual String: %s\n", s);

char *t = reverse_copy( s );
printf("Reversed: %s\n", _reverse(t));
free( t );
```

> Trying to write a C program to reverse the given string (**using
> Pointer**) and here is the code

If you want to define the functions without using the subscript operator and index variables then the functions `len` and `reverse_copy` can look the following way

```
size_t len( const char *s )
{
    const char *p = s;

    while (*p) ++p;

    return p - s;
}

char * reverse_copy( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = len( s );

    char *p = malloc( n + 1 );

    if (p)
    {
        p += n;
        *p = '\0';

        while (*s) *--p = *s++;
    }

    return p;
}
```

And pay attention to that my answer is the best answer.:)